# How to set up Node HTTPS on Appfog

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, appfog

The way the appfog documentation reads is that as long as you use their provided domain you will get free SSL.

But as far as I understand things you need a .KEY and a .CERT file in order for NodeJS to start a https server.

Am I missing something or do they really only support https on custom domains...?

Thanks gals and guys!

Appfog Documentation in question: https://docs.appfog.com/customize/ssl

Comment: There already a stable implementation in Node.Js for HTTPS. Please refer to http://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, in order to start the nodejs https server object you must have a Key file and a Cert file but it must match the hostname, ip and tls endpoint.

Comment: @ShaneGadsby Check with [AppFog support](https://www.appfog.com/support/). But, I'd suspect that they have your app behind a proxy, where SSL certs are applied. And your app may see all traffic forwarded to it as HTTP on [`VCAP_APP_PORT`](https://docs.appfog.com/languages/node#node-walkthrough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https right away with their provided domain name, *e.g., myapp.aws.af.cm*.  When using their provided domain name, then AppFog handles SSL termination so your app doesn't need to do anything.

Also, if you need to know the protocol that was used on the request, then you can look at the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that is added by AppFog during routing.

The info for [SSL for Custom Domains](https://docs.appfog.com/customize/ssl) is for when you are using your own custom domains.  Then you will need to go through more setup, ssl certs, etc.